# GitLab + apache + Phusion Passenger -> No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, apache, passenger, gitlab

I'm installing Gitlab using the official manual https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/install/installation.md but I don't want to use ngix, instead I'm using apache with passenger. I must admit that I'm still a linux newbie.

Anyway, here's the error:

> Error message: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

And here's my apache config:

> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    RailsBaseURI /gitlab
    RackBaseURI /gitlab
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/gitlab>
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This config (http://laurii.info/2012/08/configure-gitla-apache-ubuntu-1004/) suggests a `Directory` set to `/home/gitlab/gitlab/public` (with `/home/gitlab/gitlab` being the root directory of the clone from  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq). Same in http://wasil.org/gitlab-installation-on-fedora-16-with-gitolite.

Comment: Your method looks more like http://shanetully.com/2012/08/running-gitlab-from-a-subdirectory-on-apache/, which requires using passenger (http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri).

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to have this in your config:

```
RailsBaseURI /gitlab
RackBaseURI /gitlab
```

As explained in the Phusion Passenger documentation, "RailsBaseURI" says "I have a Rails **2** app under that URI". Gitlab is a Rails 3 app, so you need "RackBaseURI". But you specified both, and "RailsBaseURI" has precendence, so Phusion Passenger thinks /gitlab is a Rails 2 app.

Get rid of "RailsBaseURI" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm most likely one of

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
RailsBaseURI /gitlab
RackBaseURI /gitlab
```

is simply pointing to the wrong directory. To which directory have you checked out the gitlab code? Does it match the values?

Btw I am using pretty much the same setup as you to run gitlab (apache+passenger) and have only DocumentRoot set.

For your reference, here is my virtual host config, Maybe it helps you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName git.your_server_address

        PassengerMinInstances 1
        DocumentRoot /home/gitlab/gitlab/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```